# Error upload file with Spring Security and Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

In my situation I have a controller class with Spring Data and validator of Spring MVC which handle form data with a template made with Thymeleaf 2.1.1

I use Spring Framework 3.2.8 and Spring Security 3.2.3.

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
public String save(@RequestParam("curriculumVitae") MultipartFile curriculumVitae, @Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result, Model model, Pageable pageable) {

    try {
        user.setCurriculumVitae(curriculumVitae.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    userRepository.save(user);

    return "/crudUser";
```

View

```
                <form id="myform" 
                action="#" 
                th:action="@{${url}+'/save'+'?' + ${_csrf.parameterName} + '=' + ${_csrf.token}}"
                th:object="${user}"
                th:method="post"
                enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
                    <div th:class="form-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('curriculumVitae')}? has-error"> 
                        <label class="control-label" scope="col"
                            th:text="#{crudUser.curriculumVitae}">Curriculum Vitae</label>
                            <input class="form-control input-sm" type="file" th:field="*{curriculumVitae}" name="curriculumVitae" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                </form>
```

The error displayed in my log is:

```
Failed to convert property value of type org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile to required type byte[] for property curriculumVitae; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile] to required type [byte] for property curriculumVitae[0]: PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile]
```

Thanks in advance for who will help me.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace & your spring configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

In the stacktrace I have forget of set the maxUploadSize in the MultiPartResolver in my java configuration file with a value more high then default.

```
  @Bean
   public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
   CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
   multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(500000000);
   return multipartResolver;
}
```

Comment: Are you using xml or Java Config?